# AppleScript: set focus to a slider before sending key presses up/down

Tags: applescript

I have an application with an interface consisting of three groups and several elements inside. Group 1 contains a slider 1 with a value indicator 1  (fetched by UI Browser).

I already manage to manipulate the slider using keypresses:

```
  tell application "GLM" to activate
  tell application "System Events" to tell application process "GLM Intel"
      tell group 1 of window 1      
         tell slider 1
             repeat 2 times
                 key code 125
                 delay 0.1
             end repeat
         end tell
      end tell
  end tell
```

However, this only works, if the slider already has the focus. If I use the mouse to manipulate any objects in group 2, than the script stops working.

I tried to click the slider 1 and / or the value indicator 1 via AppleScript but this did not work. Any hints deeply appreciated!

Comment: Does this not work?: `set value of slider 1 to <0.0-1.0>`

Comment: Try putting `set focused of it to true` at the top of the `tell slider 1` tell block to ensure it always gets focus. (untested), and try @user309603's `set value` solution.

Comment: Thanks, setting the slider directly does work well. The set focused approach does not work.